# formatter:'actions', onEdit: setColProp

Tags: php, javascript

Sorry for my english. This questions is about jqgrid js library

I have formatter:'actions',

and there is

```
onEdit: function (rowid) {
var cellvalue = $(this).getCell(rowid,'Network_ID'); // I get here valus which needs as parameter below

var link = '<?php echo $base_url.'index.php/hosts/getListOfHosts/';?>'+cellvalue+'';

$(this).setColProp('Parent_Host', {

editoptions:{

     dataUrl: link

     }

 }); //setColProp ends

} //onEdit end
```

I will try to describe in my awful english -

when I click on the edit button, I am getting a list ( index.php/hosts/getListOfHosts -> doing a list with parameter cellvalue that contained in hidden column Network_ID)

and at the first click this list does not appear at the Parent_Host column (in the SetColProp)

at the second click on another line the list shows up in the with Parent_Host column with the valid cell value (from hidden column Network_ID)

and clicking further below the grid lines on edit buttons, all Parent_Host are having each lists and all is ok

but when I've got the line where the cell value (from hidden column Network_ID) another e.g. 2 instead of 1 like in previous grid lines (assume I have cellvalue = 1 from 1st -> 15th and from 16th I have cellvalue = 2) then obviously I must get 'index.php/hosts/getListOfHosts/' with parameter 2, but I am getting previous parameter 1, and such a thing happenes

e.g. if I click the edit on line with Network_ID = 3, then I click the edit on line with Network_ID = 6, I will got the list  1st time empty (cuz at the first click this list does not appear) and 2nd list will be with parameter 3 but real has to be 6.

Do you get me?

Apologies again for bad English.

Also I have to pass this cellvalue parameter (Network_ID) to the editUrl which is out of the namespace of the onEdit formatoptions of the formatter action.

Please kindly help me.